# Is using 'specially' correct in such cases?

Tags: difference

I've heard both variants and now can't really tell if using 'specially' is ever correct in such cases:

1. You mustn't listen to loud music, especially at night.
2. You mustn't listen to loud music, specially at night.

Comment: This question gets asked on the internet often. I wonder if you managed to find any of [these articles and grammar blogs](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=meaning+of+specially+vs+especially) when you were doing your research.

Comment: I'm kinda sleepy, really, 0:16am here.

Comment: Most likely, when you hear 'specially', it is simple a contraction of the word 'especially', rather than the actual word 'specially'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my short and sweet explanation. The adverb *especially* basically means *specifically*. The adverb *specially*, on the other hand, means *in a special manner* or *for a special purpose or occasion*. So, your first example is fine while the other one is not:

> You must not listen to loud music, **especially** at night. *(You should not listen to loud music in general and specifically at night.)*

An example with *specially*:

> This meal was prepared **specially** for you, sir. No one else here gets treated like you. *(The meal was prepared for a special purpose.)*

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/specially: "*spoken* much more than usual, or much more than other people or things SYN especially"; besides, *especially* can also mean "for a special purpose".

Comment: To mark this use of "specially" as dialect of *especially*, add an apostrophe to represent the missing syllable:  *The teacher done told me I outta be **'specially** good at lawyerin', 'cause anytime I'm late to class I always seem to come up with an outrageous but believable excuse why.*